# How to set datatables row color with javascript when using: table.row.add?

Tags: javascript, datatables

First i init my table:

```
var table = $('#indexedDB_table').DataTable();
```

Then i add rows in a loop..

```
table.row.add( [
    cursor.value.art_nr,
    cursor.value.article,
    '<button>click me</button>'
] ).draw();
```

Now.. if the value of: `if(cursor.value.status == "1"){`
i'd like to make the row yellow.

How should i do that?
Is it possible to do it int the "table.row.add" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first you will want to actually use the [rows.every()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every()) API.

Outside of your rows.every() function, create an empty string `var statusClass='';`, then inside of your rows.every() you will want to declare your data and get the api with

`var data = this.data(); var api = $.fn.dataTable.Api('#indexedDB_table');`

Based on your condition, you will want to have the following in your `rows.every()` function:

```
if(cursor.value.status == "1"){
   statusClass = 'yellow';
}
//when you return the rowGroup do the following:
return $('<tr/>').addClass(statusClass)
    .append('<td colspan="12" style="text-align: left;"">' + group + " (" + rows.count() + ")" + "</td>")
    .attr('data-name', all)
    .toggleClass('collapsed', collapsed);
```

Lastly, you will want to add the following in your CSS:

```
 table.dataTable tr.dtrg-group.yellow td {
     background-color: #ffff66 !important;
}
 .yellow {
     background-color: #ffff66 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
        "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex){
            if( data[2] ==  `someVal`){
                $(row).addClass('redClass');
            }
        }
    });
```

for more [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/36595/change-the-row-color-based-on-column-data)